# C - Manipulating three 8-bit chars into 24-bit chunk into four 6-bit chunks

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

Given three char inputs a,b,c, how can I turn these three 8-bit values into one 24 bit value. And next, how can I turn that 24 bit value into four separate 6-bit values.

For example:

> a = ascii 'A' = 0x41 = 0100 0001
>
> b = ascii 'B' = 0x42 = 0100 0010
>
> c = ascii 'C' = 0x43 = 0100 0011
>
> allTogether = 010000010100001001000011
>
> sixBit1 = 010000
>
> sixBit2 = 010100
>
> sixBit3 = 001001
>
> sixBit4 = 000011

Now for the implementation, I was thinking of making allTogether an int because it can hold 32 bits, and then shifting the chars holding 'A', 'B' and 'C' left onto the int, but I'm not sure how much to shift left by. As for getting the four six-bit values, I don't know how to do that and I don't know what data type I should use. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Generally the size of all integer types depends on platform. `int` can on some system be 16 bits. If you want a fixed-size integer, use e.g. `uint32_t`.

Comment: With a union of bitfields.

Comment: You can't be sure how bit-fields will be laid out.  Per 6.7.2.1 of the C Standard ( http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf )

Comment: "An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit-field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined. The alignment of the addressable storage unit is unspecified."

Answer (score -1):

the implementation would be similar to the following

```
unsigned int a = 'A'; // = 0x41 = 0100 0001

unsigned int b = 'B'; // = 0x42 = 0100 0010

unsigned int c = 'C'; // = 0x43 = 0100 0011

unsigned int allTogether = 0 // 010000010100001001000011

unsigned int sixBit1 = 0; // 010000
unsigned int sixBit2 = 0; // 010100
unsigned int sixBit3 = 0; // 001001
unsigned int sixBit4 = 0; // 000011

allTogether = (a<<16)||(b<<8)||c;

sizbit1 = (allTogether&0x00FC0000)>>18;
sizbit2 = (allTogether&0x0003F000)>>12;
sizbit3 = (allTogether&0x00000FC0)>>6;
sizbit4 = (allTogether&0x0000003F);
```

Comment: oops, this: `allTogether = (a<<16)||(b<<8)||c;` should be: `allTogether = (a<<16)|(b<<8)|c;`

Comment: when you downvoted, be nice enough to leave a comment as to why you downvoted.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char c1, c2, c3;

    c1 = 'A';
    c2 = 'B';
    c3 = 'C';

    uint32_t allTogether = c1 << 16 | c2 << 8 | c3;
    uint32_t sixBit1 = (allTogether & (0b111111 << 18)) >> 18;
    uint32_t sixBit2 = (allTogether & (0b111111 << 12)) >> 12;
    uint32_t sixBit3 = (allTogether & (0b111111 << 6)) >> 6;
    uint32_t sixBit4 = (allTogether & 0b111111);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that `0b111111` is a binary literal supported by GCC and LLVM and possibly a few others but not all compilers. If your compiler doesn't support it, replace with `127`.

Comment: binary constants are a gcc extension raises 3 of the warnings from this code.  the unused parameters argc and argv[] raise 3 more warnings.   the unused variables sixBitx raises 3 more warnings.   So the code is not portable and does not cleanly compile.